# Informix foreign key constraint lost

Tags: schema, informix, ddl, liquibase

**Informix - Foreign key constraints are dropped automatically when the reference table is altered.**

---

There are two tables - `table_main` & `table_reference`. A column in `table_main`, say `reference_id` has foreign key constraint to a `table_reference.id`. These tables are created using liquibase changesets and the foreign key constraint is successfully created during table creation part.
But in future, more changesets are added to `table_reference` table, that alters the table schema as well. Finally after all changesets are run, when we check the constraints list on `table_main`, the foreign key constraint is missing. This issue is observed on Informix DB. Any idea on this, folks?

Comment: If problem is actual. Show **dbschema -q -ss -d dbname -t table_main** and **dbschema -q -ss -d dbname -t table_reference**. Version of Informix? **update statistics**?

Comment: What are the alter commands you are running? Dropping the index may be something informix is doing behind the scenes automatically

Comment: Nathan, in the reference table(say table_reference), the alter commands executed are <update> for column c1, <addDefaultValue> for column c1, <addNotNullConstraint> for column c1, <addColumn> for new column c2 & c3,<dropColumn> for existing column c3 and again <addColumn> for column c3. And none of the new changesets are modifying the primary key column which acts as a foreign key.